# New line formatting using xml in python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program which will get information from an xml in the form of questions and answers. When getting the data from the xml below and putting the data into a dictionary I get this

XML:

```
<data>
    <subject name="Geography">
        <easy>
            <question>What is the capital of England?
                <option1>London</option1>
                <option2>Bristol</option2>
                <answer>1</answer>
            </question>
        </easy>
    </subject>
</data>
```

Dictionary made:

```
{'What is the capital of England?\n                ': ['London', 'Bristol', '1']}
```

Is there any way to eliminate the new line and the white space from within the xml file while being able to keep the same indentation on the file, or must I remove the extra line and whitespace in python?

The code I am currently using to import the data is as follows:

```
def getQuestions(topic, difficulty, xmlFile):
    tree = et.parse(xmlFile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    questions={}
    for i in root.findall('.//*[@name="'+topic+'"]/'+difficulty+'/question'):
            #print(i.text)
            questions[i.text]=[]
            for j in i:
                questions[i.text].append(j.text)
    return questions
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Given a string `s` you can remove white space at the right end of it using `s.rstrip()`. Newlines are considered white space too.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I wanted

Comment: You're most welcome.